# Evaluate the Nabla Value for Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

> You are given $\nabla f(0, 1) = (3, 4)$, let $h(x, y) = f(y - x - 1, y - x)$, what is $\nabla h(4, 3)?$

To my understanding cant we just do

$$\nabla h(4, 3) = \nabla f(0, 1) = (3, 4)$$

Or do we have to go through the process of finding $h_x(0, 1)$ and $h_y(0, 1)$?

Comment: I would also say that you are correct in just substituting $x$ and $y$ in the expression...

Comment: You may need to look up the chain rule and apply it to $h$.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to MSE, :) you can vote up the answers that were useful for you by using the arrows next to each answer. Also, you can choose the best answer that fits your question by using the check mark next to answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the chain rule appropriately. I have seen many fellas who become confused when things come to chain rule. My experience tells me that the confusion is mostly due to inappropriate notations that are used.

Note that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},\,\nabla f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$. Also, we have a function which is not defined explicitly in the question, i.e.

\begin{align*}
g\,:&\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2 \\
&(x,y)\to(y-x-1,y-x)
\end{align*}

next, we have the following

$$h=f \circ g$$

Consequently, by the chain rule we have

$$\nabla h=\nabla[f\circ g]=\Big[[\nabla f]\circ g\Big]\cdot\nabla g$$

when we write the above functional equation at $(x,y)$, we get

\begin{align*}
\nabla h(x,y)&=\Big[[\nabla f]\circ g\Big](x,y)\cdot\nabla g(x,y) \\
&=\nabla f\big(g(x,y)\big)\cdot\nabla g(x,y) \\
&=\nabla f\big(y-x-1,y-x\big)\cdot\nabla g(x,y)
\end{align*}

I think you can proceed now.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, by definition
$$
\nabla h(x_0,y_)) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
h_x(x_0,y_0) \\
h_y(x_0,y_0)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In your case, for instance,
$$
h_x(x_0,y_0)= f_x(x_0,y_0) \frac{\partial (y-x-1)}{\partial x} + f_y(x_0,y_0) \frac{\partial (y-x)}{\partial y}.
$$
Of course all derivatives must be evaluated at $(x_0,y_0)$. Can you conclude?